# Like F, like S, like GS

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**I've given you the first word of a 4-word phrase. You'll find the whole phrase once you solve the puzzle below.**

---

[image]

Hint 1

> [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The four-word phrase could be:

> **related pharaohs of Giza**.

The crossed-out boxes and the magic squares.

> The image of the boxes describes a bird's-eye view – as the hint tells us – of the [pyramids at Giza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giza_pyramid_complex). The pyramids are the tombs of **Khufu**, his son **Khafre** and his grandson **Menkaure**. We can remove the letters of each Pharaoh from the respective grid. The remaining letters spell **pharaohs**.
>
> ```
>     P + +       + H O       S + +
>     A + R       + + +       + + +
>     H + +       + + A       + + +
> ```

The phrase:

> The first word, **related**, was already given. The word found in the squares, **pharaohs**, is the next word and the (G) hints a the location of the pyramids: **of Giza**.

Credit:

> My initial answer prposed the better-known phrase "curse of the pharaohs", but I was trying to see something that wasn't there. The OP Prim3numbah and samm82 were a bit embarassed by my ignorance and made helpful comments. In fact, they practically spelled out the answer for me.  Thanks for that.

Comment: Great! The first word actually refers to the word you see at the bottom of the puzzle - "related". You have the word after "related", so 2 out of 4 words. So you're almost done. You just have to make sense of "(G)". What can it possibly stand for? As for the title, look up how they're related, hopefuly you'll see how.

Comment: rot13(gur guerr cunenbuf ner eryngrq, V zrna.)

Comment: I think the title expands into rot13(Yvxr Sngure, yvxr Fba, yvxr TenaqFba), which ties into this theme.

Comment: @samm82 Yes, exactly

Comment: You pretty much solved this puzzle. Regarding (G), rot13(Vg'f whfg "bs Tvmn")

Comment: Okay, I think I see what's going on here now. Thanks for guiding me, but while the revised answer I'm about to post will be of a four-word phrase, it's not a phrase that sounds familiar to me; I think it's a bit arbitrary, but perhaps I'm missing something -- again.

Comment: @MOehm You're right, it was arbitrary, I just chose to use that phrase because it emphasized on them being "related" somehow. Well done!

Comment: Yeah. I think that held me up a little. Never mind. I liked the principal idea of the puzzle and the aha moment when I saw what the checkboxes meant.